# Magento2 redirecting to /defaultsite for homepage

Tags: magento2, redirect

Question fairly self explanatory but how do you prevent the homepage of a new Magento2 install redirecting to www.domain.com/defaultsite ? It should simply go to www.domain.com

We are using latest version 2.1.8

It occurs in both developer or production mode. Cache cleared in var folder. Have ran setup:upgrade and recompiled etc. The .htaccess file is the default one that comes with Magento2 and has no edits. Same scenario for our env.php file in app/etc folder.

Comment: I've never had this problem, do you have stores configured in the admin? Did you use an existing database maybe? Check the db core_config base_url options too

Comment: Standard Magento2 install, put in place from Plesk on Linux server through server applications area. Category and product pages load fine, it's just the homepage that redirects to /defaultsite and puts a 404 error up

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me today.. out of the blue, the home page started directing to /defaultsite instead of /

Coincidentally, when I logged into admin to see what had happened there was a system notification message from a 3rd party extension developer that I had installed a few days prior offering me a new hosting solution. I uninstalled this developer's extension and my site started directing to the home page normally again.